# Solving for the values required to make a 5x5 symmetrical matrix singular

Tags: c, math, matrix

I have a 5x5 matrix that looks like this (specifically, it's a Cayley-Menger matrix of side lengths from a 4 point shape embedded into a plane):

[image: cayley_matrix]

I am trying to solve for the value(s) that would make the matrix singular (so the determinant is equal to zero) if all other values are known, ie:

```
a: 2.357086
b: 2.017018
c: 2.681643
d: <unknown>
e: 2.900140
f: 3.261168
```

In the above example, I've just left out d for demonstration purposes (the answer would be 1.597908 though, if one were to solve the matrix). It could be a, b, c, d, e, or f that are missing- but only one, and only ever one.

How could I solve for this in code in a fairly generic manner? Ultimately I'm looking to create a function where I can pass in the 5 required variables and an index parameter that determines the unknown to solve for, then return all the possible answers (which will likely be 0, 1, or 2 possible answers)- something like this:

```
vector2 SolveForMissingSide(float sides[], int index)
{
    // Do something here, return 0, 1, or 2 answers
}

float sides[] = {2.357086, 2.017018, 2.681643, 0, 2.900140, 3.261168};
//                                             ^
//                        4th side set to zero here because it's unknown

// Call the solver to solve for the 4th unknown side, or "d" in this case

vector2 missingSides = SolveForMissingSides(sides, 4);

printf("The length of side d is either: %f or %f\n", missingSides[0], missingSides[1]);
```

Unfortunately I don't have access to anything like Eigen or numpy here, since I'm trying to write a function for an embedded device that has fairly limited access to C-like facilities (the usual math functions like sqrt, sin/cos/tan, etc, etc are available though).

Comment: It would be laborious but you could work out the general equation for the determinant on paper and rearrange the equation to a quadratic to solve for each of your variables in terms of the others.

Comment: Is it a requirement to write it in C? Consider using a computer algebra system to do the tedious stuff. You could try Sympy (which is Python) or Maxima (which has its own programming language). In outline, you would do something like: define the general matrix; get the deterrminant as a polynomial in the variables a, b, c, d, e, and f; substitute values for some of the variables; solve whatever's left over for its roots. Also, consider replacing a^2, b^2, c^2, etc. with simple variables, let's call them A = a^2, B = b^2, C = c^2, etc., so you have a quadratic instead of a quartic to solve.

Comment: I was a little hasty; I see now C is a requirement. Still, you can use a computer algebra system to work out the equations and then print them out in a notation which can be directly pasted into C code. You could work out the 5 equations for A, B, C, D, E, and F (as defined above) in terms of the other variables and then just branch to whichever is needed. (You could try to handle it all in one function but you would need to reinvent some computer algebra wheels -- that doesn't really seem necessary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is not very relevant in general,
but since a challenging question was asked, here it goes.

I started by computing the determinant in Mathematica:

```mathematica
det = {{0, a^2, e^2, d^2, 1},{a^2, 0, b^2, f^2,1}, {e^2, b^2, 0, c^2, 1}, {d^2, f^2, c^2, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 0}} //Det
```

After some manipulation, C code generation and using
`a2 = a^2, b2 = b^2, ....` the determinant was reduced to:

```
det = -2*(a2*a2*c2 - a2*b2*c2 - a2*b2*d2 + a2*b2*e2  + a2*c2*c2 - a2*c2*d2 - a2*c2*e2 - a2*c2*f2 +
 a2*d2*f2 - a2*e2*f2 + b2*b2*d2 - b2*c2*d2 + b2*c2*f2 + b2*d2*d2 - b2*d2*e2 - b2*d2*f2 -
 b2*e2*f2 + c2*d2*e2 - c2*e2*f2 - d2*e2*f2 + e2*e2*f2 + e2*f2*f2)
```

Since we need to solve the equation `det = 0`, we ignore the
`-2` multiplicative factor and what remains is a sum of
22 terms consisting in a `+1` or `-1` factor and the
multiplication of three of the six variables `a2, b2, ...`.

It's likely that there's a logic to these terms so they can be generated in a smart way, e.g., something related to the signatures of permutations of the variables. Still, I did not spend too much effort trying to find that logic, and instead just hardcoded them from Mathematica.

These terms are thus implemented as an array `int terms[22][4]` the four integers corresponding to each term are: first the `+1` or `-1` coefficient, then the three indices of the variables
in the order `a2->0`, `b2->1`, ... `f2->5`.

Since we know five of the six variables `a2, b2, ..., f2`,
it easy to find the three coefficients of the second degree
equation for `det = 0`.

Here's the implementation - sorry for using `double`s instead of `float`s and a different function signature (however, there are four possible solutions and I don't know which one to select),
but I'm sure the OP can adapt it:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const int terms[22][4] = {
        {+1, 0, 0, 2}, //+a2*a2*c2
        {-1, 0, 1, 2}, //-a2*b2*c2
        {-1, 0, 1, 3}, //-a2*b2*d2
        {+1, 0, 1, 4}, //+a2*b2*e2
        {+1, 0, 2, 2}, //+a2*c2*c2
        {-1, 0, 2, 3}, //-a2*c2*d2
        {-1, 0, 2, 4}, //-a2*c2*e2
        {-1, 0, 2, 5}, //-a2*c2*f2
        {+1, 0, 3, 5}, //+a2*d2*f2
        {-1, 0, 4, 5}, //-a2*e2*f2

        {+1, 1, 1, 3}, //+b2*b2*d2
        {-1, 1, 2, 3}, //-b2*c2*d2
        {+1, 1, 2, 5}, //+b2*c2*f2 
        {+1, 1, 3, 3}, //+b2*d2*d2 
        {-1, 1, 3, 4}, //-b2*d2*e2 
        {-1, 1, 3, 5}, //-b2*d2*f2 
        {-1, 1, 4, 5}, //-b2*e2*f2 

        {+1, 2, 3, 4}, //+c2*d2*e2 
        {-1, 2, 4, 5}, //-c2*e2*f2 

        {-1, 3, 4, 5}, //-d2*e2*f2 

        {+1, 4, 4, 5}, //+e2*e2*f2
        {+1, 4, 5, 5}, //+e2*f2*f2
};

void solveDet(int unknownIdx, double knownValues[5], int *nSolutions, double solutions[4]){
    // all known vales squared, and 1 for the unknown variable
    double allSqrValues[6];
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        allSqrValues[i] = i < unknownIdx ? knownValues[i] :
                i == unknownIdx ? 1 : knownValues[i-1];
        allSqrValues[i] *= allSqrValues[i];
    }
    double a = 0, b = 0, c = 0; // coeffs of second degree equation
    for(int iTerm = 0; iTerm < 22; iTerm++){
        const int* term = terms[iTerm];
        double term_value = term[0] * allSqrValues[term[1]] *
                allSqrValues[term[2]] * allSqrValues[term[3]];
        // the number of occurrences of the unknown variable in the term
        int nOccurrences = (term[1] == unknownIdx) +
                (term[2] == unknownIdx) + (term[3] == unknownIdx);
        if(nOccurrences == 2){ //x^2
            a += term_value;
        }
        else if(nOccurrences == 1){ //x^1
            b += term_value;
        }
        else{ //x^0 - no x
            c += term_value;
        }
    }
    // The solution of the 2nd degree equation
    double sqrtDelta = sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c),
        x1 = (-b - sqrtDelta)/2/a,
        x2 = (-b + sqrtDelta)/2/a;
    // return ± the square root of the positive solutions - 0, 2, or 4 solutions
    *nSolutions = 0;
    if(x1 >= 0){
        solutions[(*nSolutions)++] = -sqrt(x1);
        solutions[(*nSolutions)++] = sqrt(x1);
    }
    if(x2 >= 0){
        solutions[(*nSolutions)++] = -sqrt(x2);
        solutions[(*nSolutions)++] = sqrt(x2);
    }

    //  // verify det = 0
    //  allSqrValues[unknownIdx] = x2;
    //  double det = 0;
    //  for(int iTerm = 0; iTerm < 22; iTerm++){
    //      const int *term = terms[iTerm];
    //      //printf("%2d %d %d %d\n", term[0], term[1], term[2], term[3]);
    //      det += term[0] * allSqrValues[term[1]] *
    //             allSqrValues[term[2]] * allSqrValues[term[3]];
    //  }
    //  printf("det=%g\n", det);
};


int main(){
    //a: 2.357086
    //b: 2.017018
    //c: 2.681643
    //d: <unknown>
    //e: 2.900140
    //f: 3.261168
    double knownValues[5] = {2.357086, 2.017018,
                             2.681643, 2.900140, 3.261168};
    int unknownIndex = 3;
    int nSolutions;
    double solutions[4];
    solveDet(unknownIndex, knownValues, &nSolutions, solutions);
    if(nSolutions == 0){
        printf("No solutions\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Solutions: ");
        for(int iSol = 0; iSol < nSolutions; iSol++){
            printf("%g ", solutions[iSol]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[Online GDB link](https://onlinegdb.com/-I2UaoZR3)

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to thank you for this answer. It's a great starting point and I'm positive I can adapt this into what I need- I've been messing around with matrices for a while now and it never occurred to me to try and break the problem down like this. Thanks again for the code, even if it's not optimized!